# ExpressJS rejecting PATCH, DELETE and POST

Tags: express, cors

I have an expressjs app that connects to a DB and performs various operations. However, all GET requests seem to be fine but POST, DELETE and PATCH requests get blocked by CORS with the error below

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'myrealwebserver' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

[image: preflight][image: request]

But I can see that there is a Access-Control-Allow-Origin header on the response for the preflight request. For reference, the request is being made with an Angular frontend app with its htppClient.

My ExpressJS Code:

```
var router = express.Router();
const app = express();
var corsOptions = {
    origin: '*',
    methods: ['GET', 'HEAD', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'POST', 'DELETE'],
    preflightContinue: true,
    optionsSuccessStatus: 204,
};

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors(corsOptions));

router.delete('/users/:id', async (req, res) => {
        const id = req.params.id;
        await deleteUser(id);
        res.send({ message: 'User deleted successfully' });
});
```

I tried changing the corsOptions and explicitly setting the allowed origin(s), adding cors to app.options() but nothing seems to work.

Any ideas and help are greatly appreciated.

Comment: have you enabled cors?

Comment: Oh the express app? Yes, like this app.use(cors(corsOptions));

Comment: I think the problem is the predlight request but not sure how to solve it

Comment: `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))`.Try adding this line of code. The program seems to be working for me otherwise.

Comment: Does not work, "has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the SQL queries and not the CORS policies. But the server still responded with CORS errors for an unknown reason to me.

So the solution was to fix the SQL queries.

Comment: Hi, can you explain what exactly have you changed? Doing so, you can help others. Please read [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).Thank you

Comment: Nice. Glad to hear it worked

Answer (score 0):

```
let express = require('express');
let cors = require('cors');
let bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var router = express.Router();
const app = express();
var corsOptions = {
    origin: '*',
    methods: ['GET', 'HEAD', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'POST', 'DELETE'],
    preflightContinue: true,
    optionsSuccessStatus: 204,
};
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors(corsOptions));

router.get('/',(req,res,next)=>{
    res.send("Done");
})

router.get('/test',(req,res,next)=>{
    res.send("Hello");
})
router.delete('/users/:id', async (req, res) => {
        const id = req.params.id;
        //await deleteUser(id);
        res.send({ message: 'User deleted successfully' });
});

router.post('/test',(req,res,next)=>{
    console.log(req.body);
    res.send("Done");
})

app.use(router);

const server = app.listen(8000,()=>{
    console.log("Server running in "+server.address().port);
});
```

Try this code. This is the one I am testing on.

Changes - `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))`

Only added above line

The post request is working for me. Kindly check if this code is working for you.

Comment: Still the same error, 502 response with "has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

Comment: Ok I think I found the problem. The post request now indeed works but patch and delete do not. But not bacause of cors but because of an error in the SQL query. It seems like the server will still respons with a 502 and cors error even if thats not the real problem ‍♂️